# Function with two different length variables

Tags: python, function, numpy, pandas, iteration

I'm trying to create a function, but it involves two variables of different lengths. My setup is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

u = np.random.normal(0,1,50)
t = 25
x = t*u/(1-u)
x = np.sort(x, axis=0)

theta = list(range(1, 1001, 1)
theta = np.divide(theta, 10) # theta is now 1000 numbers, going from 0.1 to 100

fx = np.zeros(1000)*np.nan
fx = np.reshape(fx, (1000,1))
```

I want my function to be the following:

```
def function(theta):
    fx = 50/theta - 2 * np.sum(1/(theta + x))
    return fx
```

but it won't work because *theta* is length 1000 and *x* is length 50. I want it to work iteratively for each *theta*, and for the part at the end:

```
np.sum(1/(theta + x)
```

I want it to add the single *theta* to each of the fifty numbers in *x*. If I were to do this once, it would look like:

```
fx[0] = 50/theta[0] - 2 * np.sum(1/(theta[0] + x))
```

I can get this to work with a "for" loop, but I eventually need to input this into a maximum likelihood function so using that won't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try map to perform the last operation on every x

Answer (score 0):

The critical piece to 'vectorize' your function in not just 1D, but 2D is `meshgrid`. See below and print xv,yv to understand it's workings.

```
import numpy as np

u = np.random.normal(0,1,50)
t = 25
x = t*u/(1-u)

x = np.sort(x, axis=0)

theta = np.array( range(1, 1001, 1))
theta =  theta/10.0 # theta is now 1000 numbers, going from 0.1 to 100

def function(x,theta):
    fx = 50/theta - 2 * np.sum(1/(theta + x))
    return fx

xv, tv = np.meshgrid(x,theta)
print function(xv,tv)
```

output:

```
[[-6582.19087928 -6582.19087928 -6582.19087928 ..., -6582.19087928
  -6582.19087928 -6582.19087928]
 [-6832.19087928 -6832.19087928 -6832.19087928 ..., -6832.19087928
  -6832.19087928 -6832.19087928]
 [-6915.52421261 -6915.52421261 -6915.52421261 ..., -6915.52421261
  -6915.52421261 -6915.52421261]
 ..., 
 [-7081.68987727 -7081.68987727 -7081.68987727 ..., -7081.68987727
  -7081.68987727 -7081.68987727]
 [-7081.69037878 -7081.69037878 -7081.69037878 ..., -7081.69037878
  -7081.69037878 -7081.69037878]
 [-7081.69087928 -7081.69087928 -7081.69087928 ..., -7081.69087928
  -7081.69087928 -7081.69087928]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).

The [`@vectorize`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) decorator allow you to define a function on a scalar and use it on an array.

```
from numba import vectorize
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

u = np.random.normal(0,1,50)
t = 25
x = t*u/(1-u)
x = np.sort(x, axis=0)

theta = list(range(1, 1001, 1))
theta = np.divide(theta, 10) # theta is now 1000 numbers, going from 0.1 to 100

@vectorize
def myFunction(theta):
    fx = 50/theta - 2 * np.sum(1/(theta + x))
    return fx

myFunction(theta)
```

If you want to trust the function, you can run the following code.

```
theta = 1
print(50/theta - 2 * np.sum(1/(theta + x)))
theta = 2
print(50/theta - 2 * np.sum(1/(theta + x)))
print(myFunction(np.array([1,2])))
```

Output :

```
21.1464816231
32.8089699838
[ 21.14648162  32.80896998]
```

By the way, I think it is very optimized so it can be useful for your statistical calculations ([@jit](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html) decorator seems very powerful).